# Как прочитать getline с переводом строки?

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Как прочитать getline с переводом строки... а то приходится самому добавлять `\n`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void FuncReadFile(char* path, std::string &text)
{
    //Переменная для чтения по указанному пути
    std::ifstream FileInput(path);
    std::string str;
    while (!FileInput.eof())
    {
        getline(FileInput, str);
        text = text+ str + "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    std::string text;
    char* path = "input.txt";
    FuncReadFile(path, text);
        std::cout << text<<std::endl;

    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getline (FileInput,str,'\0');
```

Comment: На самом деле Вы так считываете весь файл (если он не содержит двоичных нулей) в переменную `str` за один вызов `getline()`.

Если там будут нули, то Вы замените их лишними `\n`.

А один из них (лишних) Вы все же добавляете.

Comment: @avp: в текстовом файле нулей нет (если это utf-16, то нужно как бинарный файл читать, если `char` используется).

Comment: @jfs, а при чем здесь "текстовость" файла?

Comment: @avp: вы написали: *"Если там будут нули, то Вы замените их лишними \n."*. В текстовом файле нулей -- нет проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы прочитать файл целиком без преобразований (таких как `\r\n` -> `\n` или преобразований, связанных с текущей локалью), можно использовать `read()` метод:

```
ifstream file(filename, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
const ifstream::pos_type file_size = file.tellg();
vector<char> data(file_size); 
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
file.read(&data[0], file_size); // C++11
```

Результат в векторе `data`. [Полный пример кода](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2236f499a1520f4). Можно также использовать строку `string data(file_size, '\0');` вместо вектора.

Вот сравнение производительности нескольких методов чтения файла в C++, используя разные компиляторы, платформы: [Reading in an entire file at once in C++](http://insanecoding.blogspot.ru/2011/11/reading-in-entire-file-at-once-in-c.html).

Comment: Почему у вас для `file.read(&data[0], file_size);` стоит комментарий `C++11` ? Вектор всегда был непрерывным куском памяти.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: вещи, которые верны для распространённых реализаций, и вещи, гарантированные стандартом—это разные вещи в общем случае.

Comment: `std::vector` по стандарту непрерывный, вы наверное с `std::string` путаете.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: по какому стандарту? Подумайте, что будет, если vector пустой.

Comment: `file_size == 0`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: вы мне расскажите с цитатами из стандарта *до* c++11, если вы считает мой комментарий `// c++11` лишним

Comment: Just like arrays, vectors use contiguous storage locations for their elements, which means that their elements can also be accessed using offsets on regular pointers to its elements, and just as efficiently as in arrays.

Comment: 1- указывайте стандрат, для ясности 2- я явно упомянул поддержку *пустого* вектора.

Comment: Вы явно упомянули поддержку _пустого_ вектора так, как будто до c++11 это было невозможно. Можно без налета загадочности объяснять на пальцах в чем тут особенность при использовании c++11 ?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: вопрос не в невозможности, а в легальности. Я не смог найти подтверждения, что мой код легален даже в c++11 (хотя он конечно работает): [c++11]: *"A pointer such that `[data(),data() + size())` is a valid range. For a **non-empty** vector,
`data() == &front()`."* (выделение моё) Речь идёт о доступе к адресу элемента сразу за последним элементом: `&v[one_past_the_last_element]` (легально ли `&*` как noop интерпретировать в этом случае). Стандарт гарантирует, что `data.data()` работает в данном случае (даже если nullptr возвращается). А легально ли `&data[0]`—не ясно.

Comment: Если сомневаетесь, почему бы и не использовать тогда data() ?

Comment: practicality beats purity. Это работает (и должно работать по аналогии с обычными массивами: [`&a[one_past_the_last_element]`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/988158/4279)). Или я плохо искал (вероятно) в стандарте или это недоработка стандарта.

Comment: И все таки, почему комментарий про c++11 стоит? В том смысле, что &data[0] как то по особенному разве ранее работал?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: найдёте в стандарте c++03 обоснование, которые разрешает `&data[0]` для пустых векторов.

Comment: Ну так его (обоснования) и в c++11 по вашим словам вроде как нет, или я что-то упустил в ваших рассуждениях.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian:  Повторюсь: c++11 гарантирует: *"[data(),data() + size())  is a valid range"* даже для пустых vector (вот этой части нет в c++03). А вторая часть, которую я возможно не осознавал, когда публиковал ответ (не помню)—легально ли, что `&data[0]` равнозначна `data.data()`. Повторюсь: *"Это работает (и должно работать по аналогии с обычными массивами: &a[one_past_the_last_element]). Или я плохо искал (вероятно) в стандарте или это недоработка стандарта"*. Обратите внимание, я нигде не говорил, что нет обоснования, я сказал *"не смог найти"* и *"или недоработка стандарта"*