# Как прочитать содержимое файла в string

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Везде почему-то описывается только обратная операция

```
ofstream openFile;
string saveFile;
openFile.open("D:\\sites\\accounts.txt", ios::in);

// saveFile = openFile.str();

openFile.close();
```

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Как прочитать getline с переводом строки?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/380085/23044)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ещё несколько вариантов (в теории, по возрастанию скорости):

```
std::string readFile(const std::string& fileName) {
    return std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ifstream(fileName))),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}
```

```
std::string readFile(const std::string& fileName) {
    std::ifstream f(fileName);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << f.rdbuf();
    return ss.str();
}
```

```
std::string readFile(const std::string& fileName) {
    std::ifstream f(fileName);
    f.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = f.tellg();
    std::string s(size, ' ');
    f.seekg(0);
    f.read(&s[0], size); // по стандарту можно в C++11, по факту работает и на старых компиляторах
    return s;
}
```

Comment: последний вариант дурной какой-то - зачем забивать строку пробелами (std::string s(size, ' ')), когда можно просто сделать .resize()?

Comment: @gbg  можно и `resize`, разница в том, что `resize` потребует реаллокации памяти, а fill конструктор (вероятнее всего) сразу запросит нужный кусок. Другими словами `resize` потенциально медленнее.

Comment: В случае взятия сразу готового string мы получим долгое и печальное забивание нулями выделенного блока.

Comment: @gbg вы удивитесь, но `resize` делает то же самое (забивает нулями)

Comment: вы удивитесь, но resize конструктор не вызывает http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413968/5533854

Comment: @gbg ничего удивительного, это же `vector`, а речь шла о `string`, для стрингов забивает (вероятно, не менее печально).

Comment: да, вы правы, спасибо за обсуждение!

Comment: Ну, если речь зашла о скорости, то наверное быстрее всего будет `mmap`-нуть файл в память (системозависмая операция, по хорошему ее `#ifdef`-ами надо сделать), а потом построить `string` из копии этой памяти. Хотя, можно и узнать размер файла, сделать `string` нужного размера а потом одним `read()` прочесть туда содержимое файла. Это проще для восприятия, а стоить будет, наверное, так же.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, `ofstream` предназначен для вывода в файл, для ввода из файла используйте `ifstream`. Проще всего читать построчно:

```
std::ifstream file("тут ваш путь");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
     // обработайте строку
     // например, добавьте её к суммарной строке
}
```

Не забудьте, что `std::getline` не сохраняет `\n` в конце строки, так что при необходимости добавьте его сами.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool readfile(std::string& s, const char* filename){
   std::ifstream fp(filename);
   if(! fp.is_open())
      return false;

   char nil = '\0';
   std::getline(fp, s, nil);
   fp.close();
   return (s.length() > 0);
}

int main(void){
    std::string s;
    if(readfile(s, "file.txt"))
       std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```