# Считывание всей информации из текстового файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть текстовый файл, в котором записаны символы, в этом файле иногда встречается перенос строки.
Нужно как-то записать всю информацию с файла в чаровый массив игнорируя перенос строки.
Пытался

```
ifstream fin("C:\\...");
char* list= new char[kolCh];  //kolCh - количество символов в файле.
fin.getline(list, kolCh);
```

Выводит только первую строку. Но как всё-таки считать весь файл?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как прочитать getline с переводом строки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/380085/23044)

Comment: Игнорируя - это как? Побайтовое чтение и проверку каждого байта на перенос строки вы же уже пробовали?

Comment: а не проще сперва прочитать (проблема может быть лишь в размере файла) все а потом найти этот перенос и дропнуть??? и да вам тут нужен  file.read(list,kolCh);

Answer (score 2):

То же самое, но циклом - *построчно*. На весь файл может просто не хватить памяти :), хотя это тоже возможно - считать сразу все. Но лучше - построчно.

Словами - "*пока можно прочесть очередную строку, читаем*"

На C++ -

```
while(fin.getline(list, kolCh))
{
    ... //  Делаете со строкой, что вам нужно.
}
```

**Update**
Впрочем, почему бы и нет?
Вот как считать *весь* файл проще всего: открыть в бинарном режиме, выяснить размер, создать буфер, считать.
Примерно так (проверку ошибок не выполняю):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream in("test.cpp",ios::binary);
    int size = in.seekg(0,ios::end).tellg();
    in.seekg(0);
    char * buf = new char[size+1];
    in.read(buf,size);
    buf[size] = 0;

    cout << buf << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот можете считывать посимвольно пока до `eof` (end-of-file) не дойдете:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::fstream fin;
    std::vector<char> v;

    // открываем файл в режиме чтения
    fin.open("C:\\...");
    // если открытие файла прошло корректно
    if (fin)
    {
        // цикл для чтения значений из файла; выполнение цикла прервется,
        // когда достигнем конца файла, в этом случае fin.eof() даст true.
        for(char ch; fin >> ch; )
        {
            // вывод значения переменной ch на экран
            std::cout << ch << "\t";
            v.push_back(ch);
        }

        if (fin.eof()) { /* ok */ }

        // закрытие потока
        fin.close();
    }
    // если открытие файла прошло некорректно
    else std::cout << "Файл не найден" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что весь текст из файла мне нужно записать в чаровый массив.
Сделал так:
int qwe = 0;
 while (!fin.eof())
 {
  char ch;
  fin >> ch;
  list[qwe] = ch;
  qwe++;
 }
Но некоторые символы заменяются странными значками ═══¤¤¤¤

Comment: @Kyubendo тут, возможно, проблема с кодировкой, либо Ваш массив не проинициализирован и там лежит мусор. Почему бы Вам не использовать контейнер std::vector<char>, к примеру, и его функцию push_back(...)?

Comment: Блин!!! Ну сколько можно!!! Ну нельзя так - `while (!fin.eof())`!!!! Да и вообще - запустите и посмотрите. Вы не сделали некоторые вещи, чтоб читать пробелы или концы строк, например...

Comment: @Harry а так устроит? Я просто нашел фрагмент кода, в котором считывание в цикле производится, чтобы объяснить подход. Детали - это уже по требованию.

Comment: Пробельные символы (не только пробелы) игнорируются. надо добавить `noskipws`, кажется.